# No style for results of my JavaScript quiz, why?

Tags: javascript, css

I produced this psychological test:

```
 <p>Q1: What do you think about XYZ?</p>
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="A1"> Agree strongly<br/>
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="E1"> Disagree very much<br/>
<p>Q1: What do you think about ABC?</p>
<input type="radio" name="group2" id="A2"> Agree strongly<br/>
<input type="radio" name="group2" id="E2"> Disagree very much<br/>
<button onclick="myFunction()">GET RESULTS</button>
<script>
counter = 0;
function myFunction() {
    if (document.getElementById('A1').checked){
    counter = counter - 2;
    } else if (document.getElementById('E1').checked) {
    counter = counter + 2;
    }
if (document.getElementById('A2').checked){
    counter = counter - 2;
    } else if (document.getElementById('E2').checked) {
    counter = counter + 2;
    }   
        if (counter > 0) {
        document.write("Its positive!");
        } else {
        document.write("Its negative!");
        }

}
</script>
```

When "GET RESULTS" button is clicked results are displayed properly but there is no CSS style applied. What can I do to make results appear on a styled page? Thank you!

Comment: You need to apply styles!!

Comment: Suresh, what do you mean by applying styles? I just want to display the answer in same page as the whole questionnaire. Basically I take this code and paste it to my page (that already has styles, header, sidebars etc) and when I click on Get Results reply will be on blank page.

Answer (score 1):

Because you used `document.write`.

When you use `document.write` the entire document, head, body, everything is replaced by whatever you write. Therefore you need to recreate a complete document if you use it.

The standard advise applies: **never** use `document.write()`. Learn about `innerHTML` instead (after that read the rest of the DOM API).

Comment: Thanks, I will go research that now.

Comment: @slebetman where did you get that information? I don't think document.write replaces the entire document.. can you link a source?

Comment: Actually, you are right, because it is called after the document has loaded. Thanks for the info.